# if transaction was refused in orderer, how world state (KVS or CouchDB) value rollback?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I'm studying Hyperledger Fabric.

And I have two questions in transaction flow.

(I'm so sorry that my english is not good)

---

[Simple example] -> transaction flow

- A : 100 , B : 50
- A send 10 point to B.
- Ordering service has a consensus (PBFT, kafka, SBFT, etc...)

1) Client request a transaction.

2) Peer checks the transaction and executes the chaincode function.

And Peer saves the result in world state(KVS or CouchDB -> A : 90, B : 60).

3) Return result to client. Client sends the result to ordering service.

4) Ordering service collects transactions and sorts them by time.

(Does consensus also.)

4-1) Create a block.

5) Ordering service broadcasts the block to peers, and peers commit the block to ledger.

---

[Question]

1. In flow2, the transaction's result was stored in the KVS or CouchDB.

   If I query about remains point of A before block creation is complete,

   Is the response {A : 90} ? or {A : 100}

   (requests query between flow3 and flow4. before flow4,5)
2. In flow4 and flow4-1, ordering service checks the transactions (by consensus?) and sort them.

   If one transaction was refused, (by consensus or some errors or etc...)

   and the block was created.

   Then how the world state (KVS or CouchDB) value rollback ?

   (rollback by transaction log??)

---

Thank you for reading my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your step 2, the peer *does not* store the state. Rather, it has simulated the proposal and records the read and write sets for the transaction (the read set being the state prior to the simulation, the write set being what *will* be committed/written to the ledger after ordering and subsequent validation against endorsement policy (in step 5).

The flow is:

1. client submits transaction proposal to 1-n endorsing peers in
   channel
2. endorsing peers simulate transaction, returning signed read/write
   set to client
3. client compares results, packages up simulated transactions and
   sends to ordering service
4. ordering service performs consensus and adds transaction to a block 
   ordering service broadcasts to validating peers in channel
5. validating peers validate the transactions in a block to ensure that
   a) the read set is unchanged, b) the endorsement policy is satisfied
   and c) all signatures are valid.
6. finally the validating peer
   applies the write-set to update world state and the block is added
   to the ledger even with invalid (uncommitted) transactions.

Hope this helps. You can find more information in the [documentation](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/txflow.html).